# Not possible to build ember-data

Tags: ruby, ember-data

My system is:

```
CrunchBang Linux waldorf (debian based)
ruby 1.9.3p194
repo ember-data, revision 0.13 (commit 83f9f6b, latest at the time of this writing)
```

More details:

```
» lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.1 (wheezy)
Release:        7.1
Codename:       wheezy
» uname -r
3.2.0-4-686-pae
```

I have done, as detailed in the [readme](https://github.com/emberjs/data):

```
sudo gem install bundler
bundle
```

These are the gems installed (`bundle show`):

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  * aws-sdk (1.11.3)
  * bundler (1.3.5)
  * colored (1.2)
  * diff-lcs (1.2.4)
  * ember-data-source (0.13 83f9f6b)
  * ember-dev (0.1 31e8214)
  * ember-source (1.0.0.rc6)
  * execjs (1.4.0)
  * ffi (1.9.0)
  * grit (2.5.0)
  * handlebars-source (1.0.0.rc4)
  * json (1.8.0)
  * kicker (2.6.1)
  * listen (1.2.2)
  * mime-types (1.23)
  * multi_json (1.7.7)
  * nokogiri (1.5.10)
  * posix-spawn (0.3.6)
  * rack (1.5.2)
  * rake (10.0.4)
  * rake-pipeline (0.8.0 65b1e74)
  * rake-pipeline-web-filters (0.7.0)
  * rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
  * rb-inotify (0.9.0)
  * rb-kqueue (0.2.0)
  * thor (0.18.1)
  * uglifier (2.1.1)
  * uuidtools (2.1.4)
```

And now:

```
» rake dist
Building Ember Data...
rake aborted!

/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:142:in `exec_runtime'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-2.1.1/lib/uglifier.rb:176:in `really_compile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-2.1.1/lib/uglifier.rb:100:in `compile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-2.1.1/lib/uglifier.rb:68:in `compile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-pipeline-web-filters-0.7.0/lib/rake-pipeline-web-filters/uglify_filter.rb:55:in `block in generate_output'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-pipeline-web-filters-0.7.0/lib/rake-pipeline-web-filters/uglify_filter.rb:51:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-pipeline-web-filters-0.7.0/lib/rake-pipeline-web-filters/uglify_filter.rb:51:in `generate_output'
/home/gonvaled/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-65b1e744defa/lib/rake-pipeline/filter.rb:218:in `block (3 levels) in generate_rake_tasks'
/home/gonvaled/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-65b1e744defa/lib/rake-pipeline/file_wrapper.rb:135:in `create'
/home/gonvaled/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-65b1e744defa/lib/rake-pipeline/filter.rb:218:in `block (2 levels) in generate_rake_tasks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/gonvaled/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-65b1e744defa/lib/rake-pipeline/dynamic_file_task.rb:154:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/home/gonvaled/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-65b1e744defa/lib/rake-pipeline/dynamic_file_task.rb:60:in `invoke'
/home/gonvaled/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-65b1e744defa/lib/rake-pipeline.rb:328:in `block (2 levels) in invoke'
/home/gonvaled/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-65b1e744defa/lib/rake-pipeline.rb:328:in `each'
/home/gonvaled/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-65b1e744defa/lib/rake-pipeline.rb:328:in `block in invoke'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/home/gonvaled/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-65b1e744defa/lib/rake-pipeline.rb:321:in `invoke'
/home/gonvaled/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-65b1e744defa/lib/rake-pipeline/project.rb:126:in `each'
/home/gonvaled/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-65b1e744defa/lib/rake-pipeline/project.rb:126:in `block in invoke'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/home/gonvaled/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-65b1e744defa/lib/rake-pipeline/project.rb:112:in `invoke'
/home/gonvaled/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/ember-dev-31e82147b572/lib/tasks/build.rake:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => /home/gonvaled/projects/third_party/ember-data/tmp/rake-pipeline-79382441a6dc8cad240db419467da802239b4516/rake-pipeline-3-tmp-6/ember-data.min.js
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What can I do to build ember-data in my system?

Answer (score 0):

Strange you can't build it. I'm on a ubuntu box:

`uname -r`:

```
3.2.13-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64
```

`lsb_release -a`:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.10
Release:        11.10
Codename:       oneiric`
```

I've just pulled the latest commit **(83f9f6b)** and after running `bundle install` to get everything up to date I was able to build it without problems.

This is my ruby version: `ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [x86_64-linux]`

When I run `bundle show` this is what I get:

```
aws-sdk (1.11.3)
bundler (1.2.3)
colored (1.2)
diff-lcs (1.2.4)
ember-data-source (0.13 83f9f6b)
ember-dev (0.1 31e8214)
ember-source (1.0.0.rc6)
execjs (1.4.0)
ffi (1.9.0)
grit (2.5.0)
handlebars-source (1.0.0.rc4)
json (1.8.0)
kicker (2.6.1)
listen (1.2.2)
mime-types (1.23)
multi_json (1.7.7)
nokogiri (1.5.10)
posix-spawn (0.3.6)
rack (1.5.2)
rake (10.0.4)
rake-pipeline (0.8.0 65b1e74)
rake-pipeline-web-filters (0.7.0)
rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
rb-inotify (0.9.0)
rb-kqueue (0.2.0)
thor (0.18.1)
uglifier (2.1.1)
uuidtools (2.1.4)
```

Maybe comparing this to your versions helps find the problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Most gems are the same version. Maybe it has something to do with the packaged ruby. I have installed `ruby1.9.3`, but it seems also things related to `1.9.1` get installed (as can be seen in the error trace). I have tried to build in another system (`Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS`) and the error is similar, but I get an extra error message: `Usage: nodejs {start|stop|restart|status}`. So maybe the whole thing has something to do with the node version installed. I wonder why node is not in the bundle, if a specific version is needed to build ember-data.

Comment: hmm, as for the node version, on my system is a very old version `v0.4.9`